# How to replace the values of a Param

Tags: bash, shell, sorting, curl, stdin

How can I replace the values of parameters step by step.

What I mean is,

For Example-
Url is
`https://example.com/?p=first&q=second&r=third`

First I want to add '123' on p param
`https://example.com/?p=123&q=second&r=third`

Then again with same URL but different parameter, such as q param
`https://example.com/?p=first&q=123&r=third`

Again with same URL but different parameter,

`https://example.com/?p=first&q=second&r=123`

What I tried:

```
while read line; do
first_part=`echo $line | cut -d'=' -f1`                                          second_part=`echo $line | cut -d'=' -f2`

    echo "${first_part}=123${second_part}"

    echo "${first_part}${second_part}=123"

done < urls.txt
```

Comment: `first_part=...` and `second_part=...` are on the same line. That is wrong without a `;` in between. Edit your question when it only is a typo on SO.

Comment: How do we know what part of the url needs to be changed? When change `p`, when `q` and when `r`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem described is a good application for AWK's capabilities.  The demo script includes samples for both URLs and **a mapping functions file** for global transformation of URLs.

This approach allows for parameters to "free float", not dependent on matching at a specific sequential position in the URL string.

This approach also allows for parameters to be strings of any length.

```
#!/bin/bash

#QUESTION:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75124190/how-to-replace-the-values-of-a-param

cat >URL.list <<"EnDoFiNpUt"
https://example.com/?p=first&q=second&r=third
https://example.com/?r=zinger
https://example.com/?r=bonkers&q=junk&p=wacko
https://example.com/?p=flyer
EnDoFiNpUt

cat >mapfile.txt <<"EnDoFiNpUt"
q=SECOND
r=THIRD
p=FIRST
EnDoFiNpUt

awk -v datFile="mapfile.txt" 'BEGIN{
    ## Initial loading of the mapping file into array for comparison
    split( "", transforms ) ;
    indexT=0 ;
    while( getline < datFile ){
        indexT++ ;
        transforms[indexT]=$0 ;
    } ;
}
{
    ### Split off beginning of URL from parameters
    qPos=index( $0, "?" ) ;
    beg=substr( $0, 1, qPos ) ; 

    ### Load URL elements into array for comparison
    rem=substr( $0, qPos+1 ) ;
    n=split( rem, parts, "&" ) ;

    ### Match and Map transforms elements with URL parts
    for( k=1 ; k<= indexT ; k++ ){
        dPos=index( transforms[k], "=" ) ;
        fieldPref=substr( transforms[k], 1, dPos ) ;
        for( i=1 ; i<=n ; i++ ){
            if( parts[i] ~ fieldPref ){
                parts[i]=transforms[k] ;
            } ;
        } ;
    } ;

    ### Print transformed URL
    printf("%s%s", beg, parts[1] ) ;
    for( i=2 ; i<=n ; i++ ){
        printf("&%s", parts[i] ) ;
    } ;
    print "" ;
}' URL.list
```

The output looks like this:

```
https://example.com/?p=FIRST&q=SECOND&r=THIRD
https://example.com/?r=THIRD
https://example.com/?r=THIRD&q=SECOND&p=FIRST
https://example.com/?p=FIRST
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML params are, by spec, orderless, so you can simply place `p=`'s new value at the tail instead of original position :

```
echo 'https://example.com/?p=first&q=second&r=third' |
```

> ```
> mawk NF=NF FS='p=[^&]*[&]?' OFS= ORS='&p=123\n'
> ```

```
     1  https://example.com/?q=second&r=third&p=123
```

same for `q=`.

if you're modifying `r=` instead, then set both `FS` and `OFS` to `"="`, and do it it like a vanilla value update for `$NF`